# In Rails show method is not getting executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Frnds I have created a controller, named products_controller and product model and also `index.html.erb and show.html.erb`
but when i call `localhost:3000/products` it get the details from database. in the same page  i have given a link to show the details of a product clearly. But it is not loading. when i clicks on show link i has to get the details of each product. but localhost:3000/products), it  loads to the same page.
result for localhost:3000/products

```
Model Name  Brand Name  Price   Discount    Qty Available           
Nokia Lumia     Nokia   15000   5.0     25  Show    
Samsung galaxy Nexus    Samsung     45000   15.0    5   Show    
Sony Experia    Sony Ericsson   4500    1.0     10  Show    
Nikon D5100     Nikon   25500   10.0    100     Show    
Panasonic Lumix     Panasonic   25500   10.0    104     Show    
Olympus Granite     Olympus     24520   12.0    45  Show
```

products_controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.select("model_name,brand_name, price, discount, qty_avaliable")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @products }
    end
  end

  #render :text => params and return false

  def show
    @product = Product.find_by_sql("select model_name,brand_name, price, discount, qty_avaliable from products where prod_id='PR1'")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end

end
```

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :prod_id, :model_name, :brand_name, :price, :discount, :qty_avaliable
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Products  List</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Model Name</th>
    <th>Brand Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Discount</th>
    <th>Qty Available</th>

    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= product.model_name %></td>
    <td><%= product.brand_name %></td>
    <td><%= product.price %></td>
    <td><%= product.discount %></td>
    <td><%= product.qty_avaliable %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', Product %></td>


  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<p prod_id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Model Name:</b>
  <%= @product.model_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Brand Name:</b>
  <%= @product.brand_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Price:</b>
  <%= @product.price %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Discount:</b>
  <%= @product.discount %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Quantity:</b>
  <%= @product.qty_avaliable %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing, why don't you have an id for your model, and why are you doing raw SQL?

It should be:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @products }
    end
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.where(id: params[:id]).first
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end

end
```

And on your views, the link is wrong, you should pass the id for the current product in the iteration

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= product.model_name %></td>
    <td><%= product.brand_name %></td>
    <td><%= product.price %></td>
    <td><%= product.discount %></td>
    <td><%= product.qty_avaliable %></td>
    <td><%= link_to('Show', product) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

link_to will do some meta programming behind the scenes, but its mostly the same than doing

```
    <td><%= link_to('Show', product_path(id: product.id) %></td>
```

Comment: So make sure to declare **set_primary_key :prod_id** in your model, and then in the code I wrote, in the show controller method do: **@product = Product.find(params[:id])**

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that you should use `<%= link_to 'Show', product %>` instead of `<%= link_to 'Show', Product %>` in `index.html.erb`

Comment: but when i tried with what u have suggested, it shows routing error....
i declared in  rotes .rb as resources :products

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', Product %></td>
```

You need to use `product`, which is the block variable, not `Product`, which is a class.

Comment: when i use product , it shows routing error..in routes i declared as resources :products

Comment: what does `rake routes` print out?

Comment: You are getting an error because your objects use a custom primary key that Rails doesn't know about and cannot infer. If you abandon Rails' conventions and do it your own way, most built-in features will break, especially named routes. Look at **rorra**'s answer above.